# Equations of motion of $\mathcal{L}= - \frac{1}{4}F^{2}_{\mu \nu} - A_{\mu}J_{\mu}$ in momentum space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, fourier-transform, maxwell-equations

I'm reading the Matthew D. Schwartz, Quantum field theory and the standard model, p.128 and some question arises.

Consider a lagrangian $\mathcal{L}= - \frac{1}{4}F^{2}_{\mu \nu} - A_{\mu}J_{\mu}$  ($J_{\mu}$ is current). It's equations of motion are $\partial_{\mu}F_{\mu \nu}= J_{\nu}$, so
$\partial_{\mu} \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}=J_{\nu}$.

Then, why $(-p^{2}g_{\mu \nu} + p_{\mu}p_{\nu})A_{\mu} = J_{\nu}$ in momentum space?

This question originates from next section in his book, p.128

[image]

Why the underlined statement is true?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just do the Fourier transform of the equation (8.94). Also, in (8.95), $A$ should be $\tilde{A}$, and so for $J$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JeanbaptisteRoux is right. Schwartz should have used symbols less ambiguously to prevent your confusion. Denote the functions in Eq. (8.94) as $A_\mu(x),\,J_\mu(x)$, viz.$$\partial^2A_\nu(x)-\partial_\mu\partial_\nu A_\mu(x)=J_\nu(x).$$Define$$\tilde{A}_\mu(p):=\int_{\Bbb R^4}A_\mu(x)e^{ip\cdot x}d^4x,\,\tilde{J}_\mu(p):=\int_{\Bbb R^4}J_\mu(x)e^{ip\cdot x}d^4x.$$To (8.94) we now apply the operator $\int_{\Bbb R^4}e^{ip\cdot x}d^4x$, so $A_\mu(x)$ becomes $\tilde{A}_\mu(k)$, so by integration by parts twice$$(-p^2g_{\mu\nu}+p_\mu p_\nu)\tilde{A}_\nu(k)=\tilde{J}_\mu(k),$$which is how Eq. (8.95) should have been written for clarity. Schwartz also uses exclusively downstairs indices, so I'll leave repeating the above calculation with [proper up/down contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Superscripts_and_subscripts_versus_only_subscripts) as an exercise.

Comment: Yes. Helpful answer, although I prove the desired formula through different(?) route( c.f. using and imitating Schwartz's book (3.58)~(3.59) (p.38) ) bypassing the integration by parts. Anyway Thank you!